# View constraints change when UINavigation's Translucent is set to false

Tags: ios, autolayout

When setting **UINavigationBar's Translucent property to false/ *(unchecked in storyBoard)***. The constraints doesn't work as expected.

**Functionality of the ViewController**: Custom camera module displaying the camera preview on a UIView.

**View Hierarchy**

- ViewController's **View**

  - PreviewView (**UIView**) for displaying camera preview.
    The **constraints** between PreviewView & View are below.

[image: Constraints]

> When UINavigationBar is **not** Translucent

As you can see the constraints are set to equal width & height with the superview but the result is not the same. The screenshot is **landscape/iPad** but the result is same even on portrait.

[image: Result]

> When UINavigationBar is translucent

On the other hand when the UINavigationBar is translucent the constraints work fine.

[image: Result]

Comment: what did you do to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Please check this Select View Controller -> IB Inspector -> (Extend Edges) -> [image]Under Top Bars Please deselect this and try.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't work for me either.

Changing the navbar to isTranslucent = true changes the view layout.  If isTranslucent == false, the view origin.y is at 0.0 (at top of screen), but if isTranslucent == true, view origin.y is at (navbar height) meaning view starts below the navbar. View height is reduced accordingly.

Why is this happening?

My fix was to adjust layout code to accomdate this change, but it seems odd that a visual change would cause this behavior.

Comment: I guess this is happening because the view is put under the navbar when the navbar is translucent, so that the navbar has something to show thru the translucence.